# django - how to pass datetime arguments to modelform

Tags: django, django-queryset, modelform

i want to filter `serve_date` field in `Reserve` modelform.

when run this form, return: `expected string or buffer`

```
class Reserve(forms.ModelForm):

    food_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Food.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, year=None, month=None, day=None, serve_date=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Reserve, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.serve_date = serve_date
        date_stamp =  time.strptime(year+month+day,"%Y%M%d")
        serve_date = datetime.date(*date_stamp[:3])
        self.fields['food_name'].queryset = Food.objects.filter(
            serve_date__year = year, serve_date__month = month, serve_date__day = day)


    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ('food_count', 'food_name')
```

Food model:

```
class Food(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Food"
        verbose_name_plural = "Foods"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.food_name

    food_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Food Name", max_length=50)
    price = models.CharField(verbose_name="Food Price", max_length=50)
    serve_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Serve Date")
```

Traceback

```
args    ()

day     None

kwargs  {u'auto_id': u'id_%s',
 u'empty_permitted': True,
 u'error_class': <class 'django.forms.utils.ErrorList'>,
 u'prefix': u'form-0',
 u'use_required_attribute': False}

month   None

self    <ReservationForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(food_name;food_count)>

serve_date  None

year    None
```

Comment: You should show the full traceback. But what's the point of the mucking about with `time.strptime` and `datetime.date`? You don't use *either* of those variables anywhere.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, edited. i had copied the wrong code

Comment: Well, that doesn't really help. You still aren't doing anything with `date_stamp` or `serve_date`, and you still haven't shown the full traceback so we can see where the error is occurring.

Comment: @DanielRoseman i'm used date_stamp in `serve_date = datetime.date(*date_stamp[:3])` and traceback is added

Comment: Yes I see that but you're not then doing anything with the new `serve_date`. You just ignore it and it goes out of scope at the end of the method; why do this at all? And that still is not the traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added the end of the my question. Is not traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `form_kwargs`:

django Doc: [Passing custom parameters to formset forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/formsets/#adding-additional-fields-to-a-formset)